# what is Apache2.conf and site-available folder used for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, configuration, apache2

I am now trying to deploy a django project on aws EC2. I followed a tutorial on Udemy and to make django project work, I should add some codes to apache2.conf file.

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Project/Project/wsgi.py

WSGIPythonPath /var/www/Project

<Directory /var/www/Project/Project>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

But when I deployed my personal websites (a few of them) on DigitalOcean, I believe I changed the .conf in site-available instead of nginx.conf or apache.conf.

Right now in my site-available folder, there are only two .conf: 000-default.conf, default-ssl.conf which i believe are set for HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443). So when i deploy a project, what .conf file should i change?

Shall i assume the apache2.conf file is the main configuration file and site-available folder is a list of its children sites?

Comment: Checkout https://serverfault.com/a/216260/493070